# run two statement in a sql procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I had no idea about procedure before last two hours ago. Now I have only learned a single query procedure so far. But if I need to run more than one query in a procedure suppose two query then how can I do that? Suppose I want to insert a district in my district table and then want to select all district_name from that table including the last one that I have inserted now. Then how should I write my procedure? here is my select and insert query given below. Please bear in mind that I am using sqlyog. My queries are given below :

select query>>>

```
SELECT * FROM district;
```

insert query >>>

```
INSERT INTO district(district_name) VALUES('District');
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What version of MySQL? as ['MySQL 5.0 supports the execution of a string containing multiple statements separated by semicolon (";") characters'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql, you can simply put more than one statement into a proc, separated by ;

Something like this should work:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc  ( )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO district(district_name) VALUES('District');
    SELECT * FROM district;
END//
```

Comment: thanks man, all of you I will need more help for using procedure in a meaningful way I hope you all will be with me

Answer (score 2):

You can write one stetement in the body, in this case procedure can be like this (without BEGIN...END clause) -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure1()
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(NULL);
```

For some statements you need to use BEGIN...END clause -

```
DELIMITER ||
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure1()
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(NULL);
  INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(NULL);
  INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(NULL);
END||
```

Here it is an article about the delimiters - [What is the DELIMITER in MySQL and what it’s used for](http://buysql.com/mysql/42-delimiter-mysql.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can just run multiple SQL statements one after the other in a stored procedure. You can create a procedure like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure()
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO district(district_name) VALUES('District');
        SELECT * FROM district;
    END;
```